# MVEL Expression not evaluating properly when pre-compiled

Tags: java, expression, mvel

Lets assume `a`, `b` are integers, and pets is of type `HashMap<String, Integer>`

When I pre-compile the expression below, the `pets.containsKey(\"Dogs\")` node is a null inside the CompiledExpression object.

```
CompiledExpression compiledExpression = new ExpressionCompiler("a > 0 && b > 0 && pets.containsKey(\"Dogs\")").compile();
return (boolean) MVEL.executeExpression(compiledExpression, params);
```

However, when I do something like

```
boolean res = (boolean) MVEL.eval("a > 0 && b > 0 && pets.containsKey(\"Dogs\")", params);
```

It works just fine and I get the appropriate response back.

Is there any way to precompile an expression that contains an object like a hashmap?

Comment: instead of hard coding parameters, you can use a  `Map<String, Object>`, please see the answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented below both works the same way,

```
    Map<String, String> pets = new HashMap<>();
    pets.put("dog", "DOG");
    pets.put("cat", "CAT");
    Integer a = 10;
    Integer b = 20;

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("$a", a);
    params.put("$b", b);
    params.put("$map", pets);
    params.put("$key", "dog");

    CompiledExpression expression = new ExpressionCompiler("$a > 0 && $b > 0 && $map.containsKey($key)").compile();
    System.out.println(MVEL.executeExpression(expression, params));
    System.out.println(MVEL.eval("$a > 0 && $b > 0 && $map.containsKey($key)", params));
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Latest version from maven repository